# Android Layout - UI Objects with the same position

Tags: android, layout

How can I have two images stay on top of each other.
In other words, the position of image 1 is exactly the same as the position of the second image; one image is covering the other completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `FrameLayout` and then put your two `ImageView`s inside it. Children of a `FrameLayout` stack on top of each vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I think [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `FrameLayout`. Adroid have an example of [using FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html). Read up on this good example, and you'll have a better idea of how to tackle your problem.